# When are the 2017 elections?

Tags: discussion, election

When are the 2017 elections? Is there a way to tell when the next one is? I checked the previous elections, but it didn't tell me when the next one is. Also how long are they?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moderator elections are not scheduled events. Instead, they are brought up as the need arises, namely when more moderators are considered "needed." As you can see from the [elections list](https://askubuntu.com/election), there was no scheduled election for 2015, because no new moderators were needed.

To be more exact, moderator elections typically happen when the community moderators contact Stack Exchange and ask for an election. Similarly, an election may also be triggered if Stack Exchange notices that the current mods are being overwhelmed by the duties of the site (flag queues, closevote backlogs, etc.).  Stack Exchange also contacts a site's mod team at the anniversary mark from the last election to ask the question, but this still does not guarantee an election will take place. [(Source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/259230).

Unless SE or our local mods really need new moderators *now*, the next one is likely to happen in June 2017, but this doesn't mean it *will* happen then.

Moderator elections tend to take [15 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361/259230), and are split up into three "phases": **Nomination**, the **Primary**, and the **Election**. Instead of boring you with the details, I'll just gloss through them real fast:

1. During the **Nomination** phase, which lasts 7 days, any user with a minimum sufficient reputation (variable) can nominate themselves to the ballot.
2. The top 30 users by reputation move on to the **Primary** phase, where anyone with at least 150 rep can vote for them. Note that if 10 or fewer candidates nominated themselves, this phase will be skipped.
3. The top 10 users (by votes in the Primary phase) will be moved on to the **Election** phase. The winners will be chosen using the [Meek STV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english) method.

Comment: If there are two mods, do they do all the work?

Comment: @UbuntuUser Not all of the work. SE is [community moderated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160960/what-is-community-moderation-and-what-can-i-do-to-help) which does a lot of the work, but the two mods involved do have the load of dealing with the flag.

Comment: I see, but still how many flags are there daily? Wouldn't that still be a lot?

Comment: I'm not privy to that information, but you can get a basic idea of the given load at any time by going to https://askubuntu.com/review . From what I've heard though, the site has been unable to flag-free for fifteen minutes for a *long* time.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that the flags queue isn't the *only* thing that a moderator has to deal with, we also have to deal with cases of abuse, sometimes a dispute between users, etc.  Also consider that some of us are active at different times, which means sometimes the flags don't get instantly-handled.  (That said, we do try and keep the flags queue cleaned up :P)

Comment: @UbuntuUser new mods do not replace the old ones - so the two new mods elected would be added to the team, not taking over from predecessors

Comment: I nominate Serg, Kaz Wolfe, Zacharee1 and Zanna.

Comment: @Zanna unless moderators step down, in which case 'then' they would 'take over' in terms of 'replacing'; that said, I don't think there's anyone stepping down any time soon.

Comment: @ThomasWard why would anyone step away from so much fun and fulfillment? No doubt there are some strenuous days but for the most part....

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix various reasons, none of which I'm privy to :P